# pandas find median after group by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

[image]

df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=';', index=True)

I have a dataframe as above and I have the following column descriptions

```
•   Id - the uuid of this delivery
•   PlanId - the uuid of the plan (the plan for deliveries of a given day)
 •  PlanDate - the date of delivery

•   MinTime - the minimal time (seconds from midnight) for delivering this delivery
•   MaxTime - the maximal time (seconds from midnight) for delivering this delivery
•   RouteId - the uuid of the route this delivery belongs to
•   ETA - the estimated time for arrival of this delivery on this date (from the eta you can of course order the deliveries in a route)
•   TTN - the time to next delivery in the route, i.e., at index 3 that would be the time distance between delivery index 3 and delivery index 4
•   DTN - the distance to next delivery in the route.
```

I need to find the the median of deliveries per route in the given plan.

the median distance travelled per route in the given plan.

the median time travelled per route in the given plan.

How may I do this?

I am wondering if this is just straightforward calculation of median where you just group by and aggregate
I tried something like this to find the median distance

```
Tx = df.groupby(by=['plan_id','route_id'], as_index=False)['dtn'].sum()


 Tx.groupby(['plan_id','route_id'])['dtn'].median()
```

However I might not sure if this correct.

Comment: Please provide sample data as text format. Can't reproduce example through image data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do to display required figures:

```py
# Subset dataframe to only have the desired plan_id
sub_Tx = Tx[Tx['plan_id'] == '869BB6FB-.....']

# median of deliveries per route in the given plan
sub_df = sub_Tx[['plan_id', 'route_id']]
sub_df['count_deliveries'] = 1
sub_df = sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).sum()
sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).median()

# median distance travelled per route in the given plan
sub_df = sub_Tx[['plan_id', 'route_id', 'dtn']]
sub_df = sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).sum()
sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).median()

# median time travelled per route in the given plan
sub_df = sub_Tx[['plan_id', 'route_id', 'ttn']]
sub_df = sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).sum()
sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).median()
```

Good luck

**UPDATE :**

So you can calculate median of route figures (nb deliveries, distance and time) per **plan_id** as follow:

```py
# median of deliveries per route in the given plan
sub_df = sub_Tx[['plan_id', 'route_id']]
sub_df['count_deliveries'] = 1
sub_df = sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).sum()
sub_df = sub_df[['plan_id', 'count_deliveries']].rename(columns={'count_deliveries': 'median_deliveries'})
sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).median()

# median distance travelled per route in the given plan
sub_df = sub_Tx[['plan_id', 'route_id', 'dtn']]
sub_df = sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).sum()
sub_df = sub_df[['plan_id', 'dtn']].rename(columns={'dtn': 'median_dtn'})
sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).median()

# median time travelled per route in the given plan
sub_df = sub_Tx[['plan_id', 'route_id', 'ttn']]
sub_df = sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).sum()
sub_df = sub_df[['plan_id', 'ttn']].rename(columns={'ttn': 'median_ttn'})
sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).median()
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, if you notice the result of the median is the same as the result from summing. is that correct?

Comment: Hello, do you have different route_id per plan_id?

Comment: I've just edited my post, calculating median per plan_id

Comment: sub_df = sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id', 'route_id','dtn'], axis=0, as_index=False).sum()

sub_df.groupby(by=['plan_id'], axis=0, as_index=False).median()                                                is that how I do it for the distance and similarly for time?

Comment: Yes it seems to be how to do it, do you get expected result?

Comment: the results seem fine, but is the result based on each route_id? because it is only showing for over all plan_id.                                                                                              plan_id     median_dtn                                                                                                          0               162155.0                                                                                                         1                243761.0

Comment: the 0 and the 1 is the plan id(I encoded the long string in the image for plan id into numericals) and the six digit number is the median for delivery, but there is no mention of the route_id, is that how the output is supposed to be?

Comment: would you have a sample of the starting data and expected output?

Comment: hi, i have uploaded a small text file here with first few rows, it's semi colon seperated.  https://file.io/afbfR0gqYaET

Comment: were you able to figure out something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219045/discussion-between-rotunjere-and-blondelg).